# How to Append Table row with specific Number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and a class = Add that appends rows when clicked and a class = number.

My question is how can I append my rows with the number that stored in the span with class number?

Here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".add").click(function () {
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" style="max-width: 10px;">Hello</td></tr>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
You can add <span class="number"> 3</span> Hosts 
<table id="mytable" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span  class="add" data-tooltip="You can add 3 host"><font color="red">add+</font></span>
```

Comment: you mean add number of rows in class:number?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you show the expected HTML that is needs to be inserted?

Comment: You mean add a maximum of 3 hosts? @RajaprabhuAravindasamy the HTML to be added is in the code

Comment: `<font color="red">` is deprecated, please use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var i = 0;
  var num = parseInt($('.number').text(), 10); 
  $(".add").click(function () {
    if(i < num) {
        $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" style="max-width: 10px;">Hello</td></tr>');
       i++;
      }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Yo Can add <span class="number"> 3</span> Host 
<table id="mytable" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span  class="add" data-tooltip="You can add 3 host"><font color="red">add+</font></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean add a maximum of .number rows

Also jQuery 1.2.3 is silly old.

```js
$(function () {
  var max = parseInt($(".number").text(),10)
  $(".add").on("click",function () {
    var nofRows = $(".added").length;
    if (nofRows<max) {
      $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr class="added"><td class="tr1" style="max-width: 10px;">'+(nofRows+1)+'</td><td>'+prompt("Hots?","")+'</td></tr>');
    }  
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
You can add <span class="number"> 3</span> Hosts 
<table id="mytable" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span  class="add" data-tooltip="You can add 3 host"><font color="red">add+</font></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Im appending row and also column depends on how many columns and row you want.

```
<label for="rows">
  Number of rows
</label>
<input type="number" id="rows">
<label for="column">
  Number of column
</label>
<input type="number" id="column">
<button id="createtable">Create table</button>

<div id="table">

</div>


$('#createtable').on('click', function() {
    $('#table').html("");
  var rows = $('#rows').val(); //here's your number of rows and columns
  var cols = $('#column').val();
  var table = $('<table><tbody>');
  for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
      $('<td>value</td>').appendTo(tr); //fill in your cells with something meaningful here
    tr.appendTo(table);
  }

  table.appendTo($('#table'));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is what you meant....

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".add").click(function () {
    var num = $(".number:first").text();
    $('#mytable tr:last').after('<tr><td class="tr1" style="max-width: 10px;">'+num +'</td><td>Hello</td><td>'+num +'</td></tr>');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
You can add <span class="number"> 3</span> Hosts 
<table id="mytable" border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>price</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Title </td>
      <td>price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span  class="add" data-tooltip="You can add 3 host"><font color="red">add+</font></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     $(".add").click(function () {
     var NoOfRows=$('.number').html();
     for (var i = 0; i < NoOfRows; i++) {
           $('#mytable').append('<tr><td class="tr1" style="max-width: 10px;">Hello</td></tr>')
    }

   });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!